# force the focus to leave a form field with jQuery in iOS when selecting non-input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, user-experience

Using jQuery or something similar, is it possible to detect when a user has clicked away, effectively removed focus, from a form field in iOS? I have conventional form which has a first name, last name, address line 1, address line 2 etc.

On an iPad when you select a form field the only way to leave that form field is to select another field in the form by clicking it or by hitting the `Previous` or `Next` buttons in the keyboard pane.

As the keyboard pane is shown clicks to other non-input elements on the page are ignored, so focus remains on the form field.

Is there a way with jQuery/JavaScript (or anything else) to force the focus to leave the form field if I click away from it by clicking a non-input form element?

Here's an example of what I mean. In the screen below, when the focus is on the `Line 1` element I can't move out of it by clicking a non-input element.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some sort of `$('body').on('click', function () { $('form').blur(); });` event?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Yes, I already tried that. It seems that you can't click away from the form unless you are selecting an anchor.

Comment: It would seem that this is standard iOS functionality. I understand that there is the Prev/Next buttons as well as the collapse keyboard pane button in the bottom right hand corner, but it would be good if it behaved the same as a desktop in the way that if you click away from the form then it treated that as a `blur`. I've not read anything to suggest that this is possible by jQuery or otherwise.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS On futher inspection this _does_ work, with some slight amendments. Do you want to submit an answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just doing a quick `blur()` on the form, that might work.

```
$('body').on('click', function () { 
    $('form').blur(); 

    // And since you said selecting an anchor might help, potentially doing a:
    $('a#whatever').blur(); // might do the trick too
});
```